Visual Studio 2022 Windows Forms changes code when moving components of the bottom interface panel
The code in the .Designer.cs and .resx files changes automatically when i move any interface component from the "bottom part of the Windows Forms Designer", as the Microsoft tutorial puts it. It happens even when resizing it.
I was wondering if someone knows why it's happening? Or any way to stop it from happening?
Image of bottom menu:
Bottom interface panel
The code shouldn't change when modifying something that ins't the Windows Form.
I tried modifying the form before resizing the bottom part of the Designer, and the code changes didn't happen.
I've noticed that what it does is moving the code, but in some instances it messes up the arrangement on my forms.

In the Windows Forms Designer, any changes made, including those to non-UI components at the bottom of the designer, will result in modifications to the .Designer.cs and .resx files. This is because the designer regenerates these files to keep track of all components and their properties to ensure the design-time and runtime states are consistent. These files store the code necessary to initialize and configure all controls and components on the form.
The .Designer.cs file contains the code that the designer uses to define and initialize the controls and components on the form. When you move or modify a component, the designer updates this file to reflect the new state. The .resx file is used for storing resources like strings, images, and other data used by the form, including any localization data.
When you modify non-UI components, such as data bindings or timers, these components are still part of the form and need to be initialized properly. Therefore, any changes to these components will also be reflected in the .Designer.cs and .resx files.
